# Team Treehouse nav bar animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

I am trying to reproduce the effects of the nav-bar animation when scrolling on their [homepage](https://teamtreehouse.com/). I understand how they can add classes when scrolling past a certain threshold with Jquery. Any ideas? If i try to animate links in the menu with opacity my content either overlaps, and if I use visibility it gets displaced.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This Codes.

**Css**

```
ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 80%;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 10px 10%;
    background: #eeeeee;
    z-index: 1000 ;/* Stay on other layers*/
}
ul li{
    float: right;
    margin: 20px 0 0 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li a {
    color: #333;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}
ul li:first-child a {
    color: #5fcf80;
    padding: 13px 5px;
}
.scroll li a {
    opacity: 0;
}
.scroll li:first-child a {
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 13px 25px;
    border-color: #68cf89;
}
.scroll:hover li a{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Html**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"> Free trial </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Sing in </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Pricing </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Stories </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Features </a></li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery have problem with IE**

```
var sn = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if( st > 100 ){

        if( sn > st){

            $('ul').removeClass('scroll');

        }else{

            $('ul').addClass('scroll');

        }

    } else{

        $('ul').removeClass('scroll');

    }
    sn = st;
});
```

**Jquery problem fixed**

```
var sn = 0;
var x;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if( st > 100 && x != 0 ){

        if( sn > st ){

            $('ul').removeClass('scroll');
            x=0;

        }else{

            $('ul').addClass('scroll');
        }

    }else if( st > 100 && x == 0 ){

        if( sn < st ){

            $('ul').addClass('scroll');
            x=1;

        }else{

            $('ul').removeClass('scroll');
        }

    }
    sn = st;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. Although there are some issues when animating in IE11, it is a bit slow so the rectangle shape shows before animating fully to a round border (border-radius:200px). Do you know how could i fix that?